# Keyboard brightness and fingerpring sensor not working on Samsung Galaxy Book Pro 360

Tags: kernel, keyboard, brightness, samsung

I'm very new to Linux and decided to install ubuntu when buying my new laptop a few days ago. Everything else has worked flawlessly, but I can't adjust the keyboard brightness or get the fingerprint sensor to work. Does anyone know how could I fix these issues?

I'm a complete noob with these kinds of things so I've been rather clueless trying to fix these, but some things I have checked and seen if I could fix the problem with are checking the kernel and the drivers.

The kernel I'm using is 5.13. When typing the command lsusb in the terminal, it doesn't seem to find any fingerprint sensors.

Comment: Please provide Ubuntu release details.  The 5.13 kernel is used by multiple Ubuntu systems, you could be using the 2021-October release (Ubuntu 21.10), an older 2020-April release using the HWE kernel stack (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) for example, just to name two.

Comment: The Ubuntu release I'm using is 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Maybe an answer: Google OpenRGB and try it (keyboard brightness)